# How to write text onto a mapbox vector tile

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I want to label stations on my map, and I would like to clusterize the stops at different zoom levels to filter them down. So as you zoom out all you get is the start and end, and then finally a single label start->end.
How do I render a text label on a vector tile ? 
I could fetch the stations as a geojson and reload on zoom change if there's no easy way to do this with tiles.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you need to encode your data differently per-zoom-level *in the tiles* or are you mainly concerned with displaying data differently per-zoom-level? If the latter, I would recommend looking for an approach that focuses more on *styling* the vector tiles you already have rather than trying to generate those tiles in a more complex fashion. You could try using a [zoom function](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#other-function) to style your data. If you're using Mapbox Studio, you can also set zoom-specific style rules in the Studio UI, which is the route you'll probably want to go if you're using Leaflet (I see the Leaflet tag in your post but it's not entirely clear what your implementation looks like).

If the former, you may need to use a tool like [Tippecanoe](https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe). This route will likely be a bit more complex, but gives you fine-grained control over how your vector tiles are generated. Keep in mind that once you've created your tiles using Tippecanoe, you'll still need to style them somehow.

Comment: The vector tiles are generated programmatically, there's no human involvement there's way too much data. Thus is a planet wide transit map.  I have got the labels to work using geojson. We can't display all the stops at higher zoom, so they need to be clustered..I could process them to denote what zoom ranges that stop should be rendered on but I still don't  know how to write text on a vector file via geojson_vt